# Unable to control the position of text in a label using justify and anchor command in tkinter.

Tags: python, tkinter

I cannot control the text of my labels. I am using place to position these labels

following is my sample code,

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1080x640+0+0')


Headings = ['Months','Days','* Occupancy','Energy \nConsumption','Fuel \nConsumption', 'Specific Fuel \nConsumption','Diesel Price','Specific Energy \nConsumption']
Units = ['2017','per month','man days/month','kWh/month','Litres','Litres/kWh','AED','kWh/man/day']
Headings_wd = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Units_wd = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

for a in range(0,len(Headings)):
    Headings_wd[a] = Label(root, text = Headings[a], justify = LEFT )
    Headings_wd[a].place(x = 20 + a * 100, y = 20)
    Units_wd[a] = Label(root, text = Units[a], anchor = 'e' , font = ("Helvetica" , 6) )
    Units_wd[a].place(x = 20 + a * 100, y = 60)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to have `labels` of `Units_wd` on extreme right of the label 
what should I do.

I have tried to debug using commands `Units_wd[a].config(borderwidth=1, relief="solid")` in previous answers on this site but they are not working when I am using `place`.

Comment: its because your labels are made with just enough space to fill the text, if you make the label larger then the max size of the text using the `width` property then you can use `justify = RIGHT` to move it to the right

Comment: I strongly encourage you to _not_ use `place`. It is much harder to get a GUI to look good and respond well to resizes, font changes, and different resolutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, problem is solved by using the `width` command to get the desired result

```
Headings_wd[a] = Label(root, text = Headings[a], width = 10, anchor = 'e')

Units_wd[a] = Label(root, text = Units[a], width = 10, anchor = 'e' , font = ("Helvetica" , 6) )
```

Thanks @WhatsThePoint